# How to create a document when the created_at field is null or does not exist in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, collections, document

When I create a document from the app, it will automatically generate a field that is **created_at** with the value of the current time

So if I don't want that field automatically generated when creating a new document, what should I do?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you using NodeJS and mongoose?

Answer (score 0):

In NodeJS, while declaring the schema of the document, remove timestamps key and its value.